# Initialize the variable only once in php

Tags: php, session

I am stuck in a problem where I need to initialize the session variable only once. When he hits submit and comes back to the same page, the variable value should be changed.

My `index.php` code is something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['session_variables_updated'] = 0;
?>
<form name="" method="post" action="index2.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>

if ($_SESSION['session_variables_updated'] == 1) {
    //do something
}
```

My `index2.php` is:

```
<?php $_SESSION['session_variables_updated'] = 1; ?>
<a href="index.php">back</a>
```

But since the variable is again being initialized, it is set to 0 every time. Any guidance on this problem?

Comment: check with `isset()` before initializing.

Comment: include `<?php  if()?>`  missing on if statement.in `index.php` session_start() was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['session_variables_updated'])){
    $_SESSION['session_variables_updated']=0;
}
?>
<form name="" method="post" action="index2.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if ($_SESSION['session_variables_updated'] ==1){
//do something
}


?>
```

Please try this. What i have done here, I just checked the session variable is allocated or setted or not if it is not available the i assign the zero to that . otherwise i allow it to perform another actions.

in your 2nd page you should start session before doing somethings with sessions

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['session_variables_updated'] = 1;
?>
<a href="index.php"> back </a>
```

Defenitly this will work pleaase have a try. this is working in my case

Comment: @AmirBhandari always welcome. please accept this answer so others can also refers this. and mark this as correct one.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please Do change one index2.php file

you have to add  after php start and before define variable

session_start();

Hope you got idea after see this.