# php session logic error

Tags: php, session

I am doing a tictactoe on php for homework, and I am stuck on the logic that changes from player to player, as it always put a X on the cell and never changes to O whenever the submit button is hit. My question is about how to make it work.

What I have so far for this is:

```
$position = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'Position');

$player = "C_$position";

//Problem

if(!isset($_SESSION[$player])){ //Also tried the function empty before using !isset

    $_SESSION[$player]="X"; 
}
if($_SESSION[$player]=="X"){

    $_SESSION[$player]="O";
}

if($_SESSION[$player]=="O"){

    $_SESSION[$player]="X";
}
//END PROBLEM
```

I've been looking for answers and I found this [Initialize the variable only once in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607336/initialize-the-variable-only-once-in-php) however it doesn't work as I applied it to my php code. If anyone got a solution I would totally appreciate it.

Comment: Yes I started it at the beginning of the php. Just copied the code where I believe there is a problem.

Comment: Ok I now did the output and saw a prob, both if are running making the O always being overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `else` rather than another `if` because with the second `if` you revert to the original value. Currently you run into a TRUE conditional chain, every conditional is met so you end up with the last conditional's value. A rough demo of your code can be seen here, https://3v4l.org/Lv7CK.

This should correct your logic.

```
$position = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'Position');
$player = "C_$position";
if(empty($_SESSION[$player]) || $_SESSION[$player]=="O"){
     $_SESSION[$player]="X";
} else {
     $_SESSION[$player]="O";
}
```

This should set the player to `X` if the session isn't set or if the current player is `O`, otherwise it sets the player to `O` (this assumes there are only two values for `$player` if there are multiples use an `elseif`, or possibly a `switch`).